# Is it possible to plot circle in svg gnuplot terminal using circle svg command?

Tags: svg, optimization, gnuplot

I would like to draw [the family of circles](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Osculating_circles_of_the_Archimedean_spiral.svg) using [gnuplot svg terminal](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_5.2/circles.html).

[image]

Svg has [a command circle](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_circle.asp) for this. All the images which I have found use [svg path](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp) not circle, but circle is better because it takes less size ( [optimisation](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-and-manually-improving-svg-optimization/)).

In [the gnuplot source code](https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot) I have not found any command for using svg circle

```
grep -nR "circle"
```

**Is it possible to plot circle in gnuplot which gives  circle not path svg command?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.  I made [a feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/490/).

Answer (score 2):

Point types 5 and 6 are implemented as

```
     /*  5 circle */
     "\t<circle id='gpPt5' stroke-width='%.3f' stroke='currentColor' cx='0' cy='0' r='1'/>\n"
     /*  6 circle (disk)         filled */
     "\t<use xlink:href='#gpPt5' id='gpPt6' fill='currentColor' stroke='none'/>\n"
```

So in principle you could place a lot of points, changing the x,y position and size of each one.  This would be cumbersome in practice because the units of "pointsize" have no connection to the axis coordinates of the plot.  You would have to empirically determine a scale factor, and it would change if you changed anything about the plot size or layout.

Here's a proof-of-principle example:

```
unset border
unset tics
set size square
set angle degree
plot sample [t=0:720] '+' using ($1*cos($1)):($1*sin($1)):($1/100.) with points pt 6 ps var
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

well, a SVG file is basically a text file. So, every program which can do some calculations and export some text can in principle create such a SVG file.
One attempt... (to be optimized). Basically, I started from an Inkscape SVG file with a single circle to get the text around the actual circle. 
Now gnuplot generates this "Header" and "Footer" and a sequence of circles.

**Code:**

```
### generate svg output
reset session

Header = \
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> '."\n".\
'<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) --> '."\n".\
'<svg width="200mm" height="200mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> '."\n".\
' <metadata> '."\n".\
'  <rdf:RDF> '."\n".\
'   <cc:Work rdf:about=""> '."\n".\
'    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format> '."\n".\
'    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/> '."\n".\
'    <dc:title/> '."\n".\
'   </cc:Work> '."\n".\
'  </rdf:RDF> '."\n".\
' </metadata> '

CircleTemplate = \
' <circle cx="'.'%g'.'" cy="'.'%g'.'" r="'.'%g'.'" fill="none" stroke="#f00" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".1" style="paint-order:stroke markers fill"/> '

Footer = ' </svg> '

set print "Circles.svg"
    print Header
    Max = 90.
    Factor1 = 12.
    Factor2 = 2.5
    do for [i=5:Max] {
        print sprintf(CircleTemplate,100+Factor2*i/Max*cos(i*pi/Max*Factor1),100+Factor2*i/Max*sin(i*pi/Max*Factor1),i)
    }
    print Footer
set print
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Shrub_model_of_Mandelbrot_set_60_10_labelled.png